# C# - Copying Excel to Word using Interop

Tags: c#, excel, ms-word, office-interop

I want to copy excel to word as a picture without using the clipboard.

The clipboard is too easy for the user to manipulate while the program is running and it sometimes misses items.

How do I do this?

Heres How I handle it now

```
foreach (Worksheet WS in WB.Worksheets)
                {
                    progresspercent += steps;
                    worker.ReportProgress(progresspercent);

                    if (WS.UsedRange.Count > 1 && WS != null)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        var height = WS.UsedRange.Height;
                        var width = WS.UsedRange.Width;
                        var MaxHeight = ((double)width * 8.5) / 6.5;
                        var heightRatio= (double)height/MaxHeight;
                        double TotalHeight = 0;
                        int RowsSoFar = 0;

                        int TotalRows = WS.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

                        int RowStart = 1;
                        int RowEnd = RowStart + (int)Math.Floor(TotalRows/heightRatio);
                        if (RowEnd > TotalRows + 1) { RowEnd = TotalRows + 1; }

                        ///Calculate Image sizes and size copy for page
                        while (TotalRows > RowsSoFar)
                        {

                            Range CopyRange = WS.Range["A" + RowStart.ToString() + ":F" + RowEnd.ToString()];
                            double  SelectionHeight = (double)CopyRange.Height;

                            while (SelectionHeight > MaxHeight )
                            {
                                //***************************************//
                                RowEnd = RowEnd - 1;
                                CopyRange = WS.Range["A" + RowStart.ToString() + ":F" + RowEnd.ToString()];
                                SelectionHeight = (double)CopyRange.Height; 
                            }
                             
                            FullWordDoc.Words.Last.InsertBreak(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdBreakType.wdPageBreak);
                            string ContinuedPrompt = "";
                            if (RowStart!=1) { ContinuedPrompt = " (Continued)"; }

                            FullWordDoc.Words.Last.InsertAfter(WS.Name + ContinuedPrompt + "\r");
                            CopyRange.CopyPicture();
                            
                            
                            FullWordDoc.Words.Last.Paste();
                            
                            

                            Console.WriteLine(WS.Name);
                            RowsSoFar = RowsSoFar + RowEnd - RowStart + 1;
                            RowStart = RowEnd + 1;
                            RowEnd = RowStart + (int)Math.Floor(TotalRows / heightRatio);
                            if (RowEnd > TotalRows + 1) { RowEnd = TotalRows + 1; }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Is your code working; if not, can you say what the problem is.

Comment: @PeterSmith The code works but I would rather directly put the chart onto Word instead of copying and pasting. when users try to copy other data it ends up pasting onto the word document.

Comment: You can insert a link from an Excel spreadsheet into a Word document. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects).

Comment: The issue is there is no standard way of scaling the chart if I add it to word. At least with a picture I can make sure it fits the page.